# play avi using c++

Tags: c++, directx

i want to play an avi file using c++ and direct X with a mfc interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. To get AVI frames you could use Video for Windows, Windows Media or Direct Show. To render it with DirectX you should create texture and update it on each frame.

[Here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article756.asp) you can find sample project that could be helpful.

Comment: the example is exactly what i needed. Thank you